# Interpretation of 0-frequency value in a Fourier Transform.

Tags: fourier-transform, spectral-graph-theory

I have been plotting and scaling some spectra for a data series that I obtained by applying Fourier Transform, I wish to construct a signal that looks like the original using the frequences. The graph shows that there is a frequency with zero frequency and amplitude $0.337007596$, which doesn't make sense to me. Reading on the internet I've come to understand that this is the "DC value," but I'm not sure how to interpret it, any help would be appreciated.

Something else that I dont understand is that the 0-frequency component has the greatest amplitude.

[image: this is the result after the transform and reescaling]

Comment: This value is the average of your signal.

Comment: Yea something like that i read, but, then i can discard?, i mean, that value doesn't represent a frequency that afects the original signal? if i discard them and after i apply the inverse transform im going to obtain the original signal? Thanks!

Comment: @P3peM4th. if you discard that value, you will obtain a vertically shifted version of your original signal. For example, if your signal is 1+cos(t), you will obtain cos(t).

Comment: Correct, thank you!

Comment: The shape of your signal will remain the same, but in the y-axis you will have an offset with respect the original signal

Answer (score 5):

The Fourier transform of a signal $v(t)$ is

$$V(f)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} v(t)e^{-j2\pi ft}\;\mathrm{d}t$$

If you just substitute $f=0$ in the above equation, you obtain

$$V(0)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} v(t)\;\mathrm{d}t$$

which is just a scaled version of the mean of the signal. Any nonzero-mean signal will have a zero-frequency component in its Fourier transform.

Comment: Then if i want reconstruct the original graph taking values of FT i can ignore that value at 0?

Comment: No, the result would differ from the original by a fixed value.

Comment: thank you so much!